# How to show products from prestashop in a wordpress post with API?

Tags: wordpress, prestashop

I am working with Wordpress and for my shop I am using prestashop (seperated).
Now I want to show some products with basic informations like price, name, image-url in wordpress.

I dont want to access the database directly, but I want to use the prestashop api.

Question: Which file of pretashop I have to include to wordpress, that its possible to use the prestashop API and what is the basic code to show a products with the article number xxx? THX a lot guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the PrestaShop web service. Here's the reference:
http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service

And here are some examples how to work with that web service:
https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/